# Increasing Humidity in the Chamber with Vacuum-dew point calculation

Tags: humidity

Initial Chamber pressure is 0.25 mbarA (milibar absolute-Vacuum)
Initial temperature inside chamber is 25C
Chamber volume is fixed (cca 6m3)
How to calculate the Relative humidity increase when adding a low pressure steam at about100 C that is generated by MEASURED MASS QUANTITY OF WATER

Answer (score 1):

If you know the final temperature inside the chamber (once equilibrium is reached) you may find the saturation vapor pressure for water corresponding to that temperature (I am not sure if the conventional steam-tables quote for very low pressures). Then partial pressure of water vapor inside the chamber divided by this saturation pressure, when expressed as a percentage, gives RH.

To calculate partial pressure of water vapor inside the chamber you may employ ideal gas equation for water vapor.